# insert data into database with codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, insert

Trying to insert a row into my database with CodeIgniter.

My database table is `Customer_Orders` and the fields are `CustomerName` and `OrderLines`. The variables are being submitted correctly.

My Controller is( `sales.php` ):

```
function new_blank_order_summary() 
  {
      $data = array(
        'OrderLines'=>$this->input->post('orderlines'),
        'CustomerName'=>$this->input->post('customer')
          );
     $this->sales_model->order_summary_insert($data);

    $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_summary');
  }
```

My Model is( `sales_model.php` ):

```
function order_summary_insert($data){
    $this->db->insert('Customer_Orders',$data);
}
```

Whilst the view loads correctly, no data is inserted into the database.

Any ideas as to why not?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you know, table names are case sensitive on most unix systems using MySQL. I can only assume, but you have OrderLines and orderlines, CustomerName and customername.

Comment: Thanks David, I have corrected this but still not working. any other advice. Thanks.

Comment: where's the view & the table structure? and you'll need to add form_validation into this to make sure you're actually posting anything

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this in your model:

```
function order_summary_insert()
    $OrderLines=$this->input->post('orderlines');
    $CustomerName=$this->input->post('customer');
    $data = array(
        'OrderLines'=>$OrderLines,
        'CustomerName'=>$CustomerName
    );

    $this->db->insert('Customer_Orders',$data);
}
```

Try to use controller just to control the view and models always post your values in model. it makes easy to understand.
Your controller will be:

```
function new_blank_order_summary() {
    $this->sales_model->order_summary_insert($data);
    $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_summary');
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the steps exactly...the $data is defined in model, in the order_summary_insert method...and in controller is given as a parameter for the called method from the model. Sry, I just dont understand this line : $this->sales_model->order_summary_insert($data); is referring to the same $data from the model?

Answer (score 2):

It will be better for you to write your code like this.

In your Controller Write this code.

```
    function new_blank_order_summary() {
     $query = $this->sales_model->order_summary_insert();
     if($query) {
        $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_summary'); 
    } else {
        $this->load->view('sales/data_insertion_failed');
    }
  }
```

and in your Model

```
function order_summary_insert() {
    $orderLines = trim(xss_clean($this->input->post('orderlines')));
    $customerName = trim(xss_clean($this->input->post('customer')));
    $data = array(
        'OrderLines'=>$orderLines,
        'CustomerName'=>$customerName
    );

    $this->db->insert('Customer_Orders',$data);
    return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I see here, you have used lowercase fieldnames in your `$data` array, and uppercase fieldnames in your database table.

Comment: Thanks Kobus, I did change this to be the same case, as per your and Davids advice but still not working. I know the model is being called and run as I can see the echo if I insert one. How can I trouble shoot this or get some feedback from the database? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps returning the affected_rows() after inserting the data? `return $this->db->affected_rows();`

Comment: You can find some useful logs in these files.
PHP Error Log
MySQL Log
Apache access and Apache Error log

Answer (score 1):

View

```
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="text" name="class"/>
```

Controller

```
function __construct()
{
    parent:: __construct();
    $this->load->Model('Model');
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('view');
}

function user(){
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $data = array('name'=>$_POST['name'],
                    'class'=>$_POST['class']);
         $this->Model->insert($data);
    }
}
```

Model

```
function insert($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('table_name',$data);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function saveProfile(){
    $firstname = $this->input->post('firstname');
    $lastname = $this->input->post('lastname');
    $post_data = array('firstname'=> $firstname,'lastname'=>$lastname);
    $this->db->insert('posts',$post_data);
    return $this->db->insert_id(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function order_summary_insert()
$OrderLines=$this->input->post('orderlines');
$CustomerName=$this->input->post('customer');
$data = array(
'OrderLines'=>$OrderLines,
'CustomerName'=>$CustomerName
);

$this->db->insert('Customer_Orders',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller:

```
function order()
    $OrderLines = $this->input->post('orderlines');
    $CustomerName = $this->input->post('customer');
    $data = array(
        'OrderLines' => $OrderLines,
        'CustomerName' =>$CustomerName
    ); 

    $this->db->insert('Customer_Orders', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert `$this->load->database();` in your model:

```
function order_summary_insert($data){
    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->insert('Customer_Orders',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cnt extends CI_Controller {


 public function insert_view()
 {
  $this->load->view('insert');
 }
 public function insert_data(){
  $name=$this->input->post('emp_name');
  $salary=$this->input->post('emp_salary');
  $arr=array(
   'emp_name'=>$name,
   'emp_salary'=>$salary
   );
  $resp=$this->Model->insert_data('emp1',$arr);
  echo "<script>alert('$resp')</script>";
  $this->insert_view();  
 }
}
```

for more detail visit:
http://wheretodownloadcodeigniter.blogspot.com/2018/04/insert-using-codeigniter.html

Comment: Hey, could you provide some explanations in addition? Your shouldn't only show code or/and link, have a look to that link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer ;)