# How to insert a data in a table in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having some trouble updating records with the Codeigniter framework. I'm using the MVC pattern and active records.

```
public function save_yarn($data)
{
    $this->db->select('sub_name');
     $this->db->from('mst_subject');
    $this->db->insert($data);
}
```

Comment: Props for the function name

Comment: problem: You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Comment: So why not to use `set` method if you actually update data?

Comment: Did you read CI documentation?https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert

Comment: @Shaiful Islam Please provide new locations to avoid future link breaks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [insert data into database with codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969411/insert-data-into-database-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should works for you:

```
$data = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'name' => $name,
    'date' => $date
);

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update

Answer (score 0):

If you're using models for your tables, you can do something easy like

```
$this->yarn_model->update($row_id_to_update, $data);
```

Otherwise, Angel's method will work too.