# how to insert a records in database in CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have my controller **Hello.php** like this:

```
class Hello extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('insert_model');
    }

    public function index(){
      $this->insert_model->insert();
      $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
    }
```

And my Model **insert_model.php** like so:

```
class insert_model extends CI_Model{

     public function __construct()
     {
       $this->load->database(); 
     }

     public function insert(){
       $data=array(
        'user_name'=>$this->input->post('user_name'),
        'user_email'=>$this->input->post('user_email'),
        'user_password'=>$this->input->post('user_password'),
        'user_dob'=>$this->input->post('user_dob'),
        'user_gender'=>$this->input->post('user_gender'),
        'user_address'=>$this->input->post('user_address'),
        'user_contact'=>$this->input->post('user_contact')

       );

        $this->db->insert('user',$data);  
     }
}
```

But the problem is this my records is not inserted in the database...

---

[image]

Comment: Is there any error

Comment: After insert query just put &#39;echo $this-&gt;db-&gt;last_query(); die;&#39; . It will display whole query . Just copy that query and fire in MySQL console. You will get error if anything there .

Comment: what you are getting error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [insert data into database with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969411/insert-data-into-database-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

```
**in controller**
public function index(){
      $data=array(
        'user_name'=>$this->input->post('user_name'),
        'user_email'=>$this->input->post('user_email'),
        'user_password'=>$this->input->post('user_password'),
        'user_dob'=>$this->input->post('user_dob'),
        'user_gender'=>$this->input->post('user_gender'),
        'user_address'=>$this->input->post('user_address'),
        'user_contact'=>$this->input->post('user_contact')

       );
      $last_id = $this->insert_model->insert_data($data);
if($last_id)
      $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';

**In model**

      public function insert(){
     $this->db->insert('user',$data);
     //check the query by
     echo $this->db->last_query();
     return $this->db->insert_id();  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, there are no any issues in code. But make sure your database `user` table having columns like `user_name`, `user_email` .... `user_contact`

```
'user_name'=>$this->input->post('user_name'),
'user_email'=>$this->input->post('user_email'),
'user_password'=>$this->input->post('user_password'),
'user_dob'=>$this->input->post('user_dob'),
```

Array key should always refer to the table column name

```
'column_name'=>value,
```

Comment: yap.....but data is not inserting only blank row inserting in the database.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong.see your call of the insert model in the controller, you can send data in your controller from view but not in model. so no post data is getting in the model.

```
    class Hello extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct(){
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->model('insert_model');
        }

        public function index(){
          $data=array(
            'user_name'=>$this->input->post('user_name'),
            'user_email'=>$this->input->post('user_email'),
            'user_password'=>$this->input->post('user_password'),
            'user_dob'=>$this->input->post('user_dob'),
            'user_gender'=>$this->input->post('user_gender'),
            'user_address'=>$this->input->post('user_address'),
            'user_contact'=>$this->input->post('user_contact')

           );
          $data['last_id'] = $this->insert_model->insert_data($data);
          $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
        }

    class insert_model extends CI_Model{

         public function __construct()
         { 
           parent::__construct();
           $this->load->database(); 
         }

         public function insert_data($data){
            $this->db->insert('user',$data); 
            return $this->db->insert_id(); 
         }
    }
```

let me know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue with your code, First of all Load the view page in hello/index
    Then check the isset of submit button e.g;

```
$submit = $this->input->post('submit');
if(isset($submit)){}
```

Or if you are load the view page on the same method, then you have to call the form action like;

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>hello/index" >
```

I have update your code

**Controller.php**

```
class Hello extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('insert_model');
    }
    public function index(){
        $submit = $this->input->post('submit');
        if(isset($submit)){
                  $data=array(
                    'user_name'=>$this->input->post('user_name'),
                    'user_email'=>$this->input->post('user_email'),
                    'user_password'=>$this->input->post('user_password'),
                    'user_dob'=>$this->input->post('user_dob'),
                    'user_gender'=>$this->input->post('user_gender'),
                    'user_address'=>$this->input->post('user_address'),
                    'user_contact'=>$this->input->post('user_contact')

                   );
                $insert = $this->inser_model-> insert_data();
                if($insert) {
                  $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
                }
        }
        $this->load->view('your_page');
    }
}
```

**Model.php**

```
class insert_model extends CI_Model{
    public function insert_data($data){
        return   $this->db->insert('user',$data); 
    }
}
```